# iPhone is plugged in and shows up in one xcode project but not in another. Why?

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I have my iPhone (which I'll BobbyUserIPhone ) plugged into my Mac the name "BobbyUserIPhone" shows up in the scheme for one of XCode projects. I have another XCode Project open that just "iOS Device" instead of "BobbyUserIPhone" like I would expect. What might cause this and whats the best solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

Often, the cause of this is that the **different projects have different deployment targets**, I.e. Project 1 has a deployment target of iOS 4, while project 2 has an iOS 6 target. If the iPhone is running iOS 5, it will show up in project 1, but not in project 2.

As @Dario mentioned, you can change your target under Build Settings for each target in your app.

Comment: You can change the deployment target under "build settings", just do a global search if you can't find it (cmd-shift-f), search for "deployment target"